# Is it possible to programatically export an array of names, emails, and subject lines to the Google Forms "Send" feature?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I have a Google form. 
I have a sheet using script that employs arrays storing a list of names, emails, and a subject line collected from my sheet

I want to run a script from my sheet that calls the form (via id, url, or whatever) and tells it to "send" the form to those email addresses.

I cannot find Form API that touches the Forms "Send" feature.

Is that possible? Or will I need to manually generate and send the emails using script the old fashioned way? So they will appear as an email with a link to click rather than the nicely formatted Google Forms email?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Form API but there is the Google Apps Script [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) but it hasn't a "send" method but it has a [getPublishedUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getPublishedUrl()) that you can use to grab the respond view and send it by using MailApp or GmailApp.

Comment: Yes it looks like they just haven't gotten to that part of Forms or they are avoiding it to prevent enabling spammers? Even though you can do all this just as easily with copy and paste into the Send page of the Form. But I guess I will be doing this using the email feature. Maybe I can force the render of the form in the mail app output, in the construction of the email itself, and fake it.